# How to validate multiple models in a spring mvc form?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have a spring mvc form with multiple models. `Color` and `Shade`

I am using hibernate validator and when I only have one model the validations work perfectly. From my research I found that best way to have multiple models with spring mvc form is to create a new model that wraps both the models. So I made:

**Models**

```
public class ColorShade {

    private Color color;
    private Shade shade;

    //getter setters
}

public class Color {
  @NotEmpty
  private String name;
  //getter setters
}

public class Shade {
  @NotEmpty
  private String shadeName;
  //getter setters
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateForm(
        @ModelAttribute("COLORSHADE") @Valid ColorShade colorShade,
        BindingResult result, Map model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "myForm";
    }

    return "success";
}
```

**View**

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="COLORSHADE" cssClass="form-horizontal" >
    <spring:bind path="COLORSHADE.color.name">
        <div class="control-group ${status.error ? 'error' : ''}">
            <label class="control-label">Color Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <form:input path="${status.expression}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>
    <spring:bind path="COLORSHADE.shade.shadeName">
        <div class="control-group ${status.error ? 'error' : ''}">
            <label class="control-label">Shade Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <form:input path="${status.expression}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>
</form>
```

**Question**

- The above setup works but the validations are not working now. how can I get validations to work?
- If I just have single model and remove the wrap around `ColorShade` model then the validations work perfectly fine. How can I get both, multiple models in single form and validations, to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
public class ColorShade {
    @Valid
    private Color color;
    @Valid
    private Shade shade;

    //getter setters
}
```

See http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e991